# Dynamic objects in Python like in AS3

Tags: python, actionscript-3, object, dynamic

In AS3 we have a keyword to define dynamic objects:

```
dynamic class DynamicClass { ... }
```

So, we can add or delete properties in run-time.

```
var dynamicInstance:DynamicClass = new DynamicClass();
// add a property like this...
dynamicInstance.newProperty = 'newValue';
// or this...
dynamicInstance['otherProperty'] = 'otherValue';
```

The I can acces or even iterate throught the whole collection of dynamic properties:

```
for (var name:String in dynamicInstance)
    trace(name, '=', dynamicInstance[name])
// output:
//     newProperty = newValue
//     otherProperty = otherValue
```

And I also can delete those properties:

```
// and delete a property like this...
delete dynamicInstance.newProperty;
// or this...
delete dynamicInstance['otherProperty'];
```

How can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A co-worker gave me an advice on this and we found a solution for this:

```
class Dynamic:
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return getattr(self, name)

    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        setattr(self, name, value)

    def __delitem__(self, name):
        delattr(self, name)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.__dict__.__iter__()
```

Here is a test:

```
dynamicInstance = Dynamic()
dynamicInstance.newProperty = 'newValue'
dynamicInstance['otherProperty'] = 'otherValue'

print [(name, dynamicInstance[name]) for name in dynamicInstance]

del dynamicInstance['newProperty']

print [(name, dynamicInstance[name]) for name in dynamicInstance]

del dynamicInstance.otherProperty

print [(name, dynamicInstance[name]) for name in dynamicInstance]

#output:
# [('otherProperty', 'otherValue'), ('newProperty', 'newValue')]
# [('otherProperty', 'otherValue')]
# []
```

Answer (score 4):

all classes in python are dynamic. you can acces them like this

```
class a:
   pass

>>> a.name="rob"
>>> a.age=45
>>> dir(a)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__',
 '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'age', 'name']

>>> a.age
45
>>> a.name
'rob'
```

**or**

```
>>> setattr(a,"job","fischer")
>>> getattr(a,"name")
'rob'
```

If you want to change all instances of the class you can easily write a for loop that ignors the instances starting with __

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem!!! I can't create an instance and access to any property like this: `instance['property']`. And adding properties to a class ALL instances have them I don't want that!